# Bug al crear wiki de comunidad

Tags: soporte, bug, estado-completado, wiki-de-comunidad

Estoy creando una pregunta a la que voy a responder yo mismo. Entonces marco la casilla de "Responde a tu propia pregunta":

[image: Responde a tu propia pregunta]

Y cuando marco la casilla de "Wiki de comunidad" recibo este mensaje de confirmación dos veces:

[image: Mensaje de error]

Es un bug porque realmente sólo hace falta que se muestre una vez.

Comment: Si, yo también lo noté y olvidé preguntar sobre ello, espero se de una solución

Comment: ¿Sigue este bug vivo? No consigo reproducirlo.

Comment: @Konamiman Acabo de mirar y ya no sale dos veces, sólo una. Parece que está solucionado. Gracias